# How to fix my llvm installation?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, llvm

So I am a new Linux user and new to programming, and I wanted to learn some of the C style languages. One of the online courses that I'm taking provides me a vm environment with clang installed and configured to help students such as myself. Since I already have a Linux Mint 17 installation I thought I'd go ahead and install the llvm infrastructure myself using apt. **So I followed the instructions here** http://llvm.org/apt/

I added these lines to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
# 3.4
deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.4 main
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.4 main
```

The I opened a terminal and executed these commands to install the 3.4 stable channel packages:

```
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
apt-get install clang-3.4 clang-3.4-doc libclang-common-3.4-dev libclang-3.4-dev libclang1-3.4 libclang1-3.4-dbg libllvm-3.4-ocaml-dev libllvm3.4 libllvm3.4-dbg lldb-3.4 llvm-3.4 llvm-3.4-dev llvm-3.4-doc llvm-3.4-examples llvm-3.4-runtime clang-modernize-3.4 clang-format-3.4 python-clang-3.4 lldb-3.4-dev
```

Immediately after these I got alerted by "update manager" that some of my packages need to be updated. I did this and my packages were upgraded to the development branch (3.5 release).

The development branch gets upgraded every few hours, and I probably don't need something this "cutting edge", what with my crappy internet and low datacap.

**So my questions are**:

1. Have I done the installation correctly and are there any steps that I missed/messed up?
2. How can I revert back to the stable branch of llvm, and not have the 3.5 release packages show up every time I call "sudo apt-get update"?

.

```
Start-Date: 2014-07-18  16:10:20
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: libllvm3.5-dbg:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), lldb-3.5-dev:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), libclang-3.5-dev:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), clang-3.5-doc:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), libclang1-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), libllvm3.4:amd64 (3.4-1ubuntu3, 3.4.2+svn209031-1~exp1), libllvm3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), libclang1-3.5-dbg:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), lldb-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), clang-modernize-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), libclang-common-3.5-dev:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), llvm-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), llvm-3.5-examples:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), llvm-3.5-dev:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), python-clang-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), clang-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), clang-format-3.5:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), libllvm-3.5-ocaml-dev:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), llvm-3.5-doc:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1), llvm-3.5-runtime:amd64 (3.5~svn201651-1ubuntu1, 3.5~svn213346-1~exp1)
End-Date: 2014-07-18  16:11:00
```

Comment: *I wanted to learn some of the C style languages* -> You don't need a VM to do this on your own machine.  Just use `gcc` or `clang` directly.  Doing it in a VM is just an added hassle.

Comment: My first reaction is that the system should not have updated you to 3.5, if you installed 3.4. The packages have different names. What did the upgrade look like? Can you post that? If you don't have it on your terminal, apt keeps history in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't want the first two lines you put in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, namely

```
deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
```

I suspect these correspond to 3.5 (trunk).

You can verify this by running

```
apt-cache policy pkg1 ... pkgn
```

where the pkgs run over all the clang/llvm packages you have installed.

This will show you where the packages you installed are coming from.

I second goldilock's comment about not using a VM unless you have to. It is just extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the problem. On deleting those lines from sources.list, and selecting "refresh" on update manager, I got the message saying that my packages were all up to date. Now should I keep using the 3.5 release or is there any way to go back to the 3.4 release packages?

Comment: Ok, I'm completely new to this. Is llvm a vm? The homepage says it has little to do with virtual machines.

Comment: No, of course not. It's a compiler related thing. My comment (and Goldilocks) was prompted by "One of the online courses that I'm taking provides me a vm environment with clang istalled and configured to help students such as myself."

Comment: @kchak I think you have have both the 3.4 and 3.5 packages installed. If you don't want the 3.5 packages, just remove them. Alternatively, I think they can remain co-installed with the 3.4 packages if you want them to be, but of course you won't get any further updates of the 3.5. :-) Personally I see no reason not to keep both installed and try them both (if you want to).